# How to create and store instances of a class at initialization?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.3, I want to bind a class `Test` to another class called `TestManager` so that the manager creates instances of `Test` and stores them to give an access to them afterwards.

In a nutshell (I mean, Python shell...), I want to be able to do this (assuming `name` is an attribute of `Test`):

```
> t = Test.objects.get(id=3)
> t.name
# Returns 'Name 3'
```

The trick is that my collection of objects is a "static" collection, in a sense that it is created at first (not by any user) and then never modified or deleted, nor its records removed or edited. It's fixed.
So here is the code I tried:

```
class TestManager:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._tests = [Test(name='Name {}'.format(i)) for i in range(100)]

    def get(self, id):
        return self._tests[id]

class Test:
    objects = TestManager()

    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name
```

Aaaand, as expected, `NameError: global name 'Test' is not defined` due to the circular initialization. Ideally, I should have a `create()` method in the manager which would take care of adding elements in the list (instead of the `__init__()`), but that would mean that the creation is not done in the manager but elsewhere.

The "best" solution I came up with, so far, is to check first in the `get()` method if the list is empty, and thus call a `fill_the_damn_list()` method, but it seems very hackish to me. Another way to do that would be to use a dict instead of a list and to create the instances on the fly at first `get()`. The advantage of the latter one is that it does not create useless/never `get()`-ed instances, but with only an hundred of them in total, I am not sure it really matters, and the hackish-ness of this solution looks quite the same to me...

As I am quite new to Python (if it isn't clear enough...), I wonder if there is a better way to do that and to keep it simple. I am also OK to refactor if needed, but I didn't find any better solution yet...

Comment: What is this circular reference good for? Shouldn't it suffice that the "TestManager" has a list of its tests?

Comment: Assign the `objects` attribute after the creation of the class. Set it to `None` the class code and right after the `Test` class code set it to `TestManager()`

Comment: This design seems like a `object` factory in reverse. It doesn't make a lot of sense how it is written. The _TestManager_ should be used to index into the collection like it is and not have to go through the _Test_ class to get to this collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design seems a little odd -- it's unclear why the `Test` class needs a reference to a `TestManger` instance. Regardless, I think the following will make that happen. It uses a metaclass to create the `objects` attribute of the `Test` class *and* adds  the `_tests` attribute you want to the `TestManger` instance it created -- which all go into making this a rather peculiar answer...fitting, I suppose. ;-)

```
class TestManager:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('creating TestManager')

    def get(self, id):
        return self._tests[id]

class TestMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcl, name, bases, classdict):
        # add an "objects" attribute to the class being created
        classdict['objects'] = tm = TestManager()
        cls = type.__new__(mcl, name, bases, classdict)
        # add a "_tests" attribute to the TestManager instance just created
        # (can't use class's name, since it hasn't been returned yet)
        tm._tests = [cls(name='Name {}'.format(i)) for i in range(100)]
        return cls

class Test(metaclass=TestMetaClass):
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name

t = Test.objects.get(3)
print(t.name)
```

Comment: First of all, I am a junior developer, so I totally agree that my design skills have to be improved, which is why I am learning by doing and by getting opinion/advice from experienced people like you... I tried to keep the question simple, but I should have given a bit of context. I am building an online card game using Django, and I need to keep track of the card instances without storing them into the database. The `Card.objects.get()` syntax is also here to have a transparent way of accessing records of both Django model objects and my `Card` objects. Am I entirely wrong according to you?

Comment: @JérémieAstori: I'm not familiar with Django and what constraints it might be putting what you're trying to do. That said, I think the main difficulty arises from is you wanting to make the objects aware of a (or the) container/collection that's holding them (the `TestManager`), which introduces a [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). General it can also create other problems, although you may be able to avoid many of them because the collection is static. Why can't you just make a `Deck` container and have `TestManager` create and use it?

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with sean's comment: your design is strange and, I think, quite useless, and this is causing problems even before starting using it. Anyway, if you want to do that you can use a lot of different methods.

The simple way:

```
class TestManager:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._tests = [Test(name='Name {}'.format(i)) for i in range(100)]

    def get(self, id):
        return self._tests[id]

class Test:
    objects = None

    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name

Test.objects = TestManager()
```

An other approach can be using a decorator:

```
>>> class TestManager(object):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...             self._tests = []
...     def init_class(self, cls):
...             self._tests = [cls(name='Name {}'.format(i)) for i in range(100)]
...             cls.objects = self
...             return cls
...     def get(self, id):
...             return self._tests[id]
... 
>>> manager = TestManager()
>>> @manager.init_class
... class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self, name=''):
...             self.name = name
... 
>>> manager.get(5)
<__main__.Test object at 0x7f4319db8110>
```

The above recipe works if `TestManager` is a Singleton, but if it is not a singleton you simply have to remember to call `TestManager.init_class(TheClass)` before accessing the class instances, and that can be done anywhere in your code.

You can also use getters for this:

```
>>> class TheGetter(object):
...     def __init__(self, cls):
...             self._cls = cls
...             self._inst = None
...     def __get__(self, inst, owner):
...             if self._inst is None:
...                     self._inst = self._cls()
...             return self._inst
... 
>>> class Test(object):
...     objects = TheGetter(TestManager)
...     def __init__(self, name):
...             self.name = name
... 
>>> Test.objects.get(5)
<__main__.Test object at 0x7f431690c0d0>
```

Comment: I agree with your comments on my design, and therefore I gave some context details in a comment to martineau's answer. I hope it will be clearer this time... but if you have any comment at all about this design, I am more than open to suggestions!! :-)